# Laravel 5 [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

> **  [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1166 Incorrect column na   me 'INTERESTED IN INTERNSHIP JOB
>   '**
>
> **in this column INTERESTED IN INTERNSHIP JOB is radio button  **
>
> **in this column SEX , INTERESTED IN INTERNSHIP JOB , AND ABOVE 18 ARE RADIO BUTTON **

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('students',function(Blueprint $table)
  {
    $table-> increments('id');
    $table-> char('FIRST NAME',50 );
    $table-> char('LAST NAME',50 );
    $table-> string('EMAIL',50 );
    $table-> string('SEX',50);
    $table-> string('INTERESTED IN INTERNSHIP JOB ',50);
    $table-> text('SKILLS');
    $table-> string('above18',50);
    }); 

}
```

Please help me resolve the aforementioned error, as I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advice though never use uppercase for column names otherwise there can cross platform issues between windows(case-insensitive) and Linux(Case-sensitive)

http://justinsomnia.org/2003/04/essential-database-naming-conventions-and-style/

**UPDATE**

change `'INTERESTED IN INTERNSHIP JOB '` to `'INTERESTED IN INTERNSHIP JOB'`

There is an additional space at the end of column name and `'`